# The meaning of "Even if I should"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Consider the following:

> Even if I...
>
> Even should I...

These all mean the same thing, right? What about

> Even if I should...

Does that have the same meaning?

"If you should ever," is grammatically correct, so shouldn't, "Even if I should" also be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break these apart.

> 1. Even if I do X, Y will happen.
> 2. Even should I do X, Y will happen.
> 3. Even if I should do X, Y will happen.

*[Even](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even)* is being used as an adverb in all three cases, taking the second meaning in the Wiktionary listing:

> "Implying an extreme example in the case mentioned, as compared to the implied reality."

So it is saying that "X" is one of the best options I have.

Numbers 2 and 3 are the same construction, where *[should](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/should)* is being used as an auxiliary verb to form the *[future subjunctive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subjunctive_mood)*.  This indicates that X is something I am only hypothetically interested in doing, just for the sake of argument.  The indicative mood of number 1, by contrast, suggests that X is something I am actually interested in doing.  However, in a conditional clause like this one, the difference between actual and hypothetical is quite small.

**Edit:** number 3 could possibly use a different meaning of *should,* that of obligation.  In this case X is something I really ought to do, but instead of doing that I will do Y, something different.  That's not really the meaning you are after, and might not be understood that way anyway, which is why I ignored it earlier.

In short, there is a fine distinction between the first example and the others, but for practical purposes you can treat them as the same.

Comment: +1 as this is the only answer I really understand. Perhaps you could mention that while it's possible to get the "obligation/ought to" meaning of "should" out of example 3. depending on the phrase ("even if I should be quiet, I'm going to talk anyway") we're not comparing that meaning, just the future subjunctive one?

Comment: @aedia: Quite so. Even should the irrelevant preoccupation with a hypothetical 'obligation' interpretation *not* have been present in other answers, it's still worth Rhodri mentioning that possible interpretation!

Comment: "So it is saying that X is one of the best options I have" is not necessary true - "Even should I fail miserably to provide a good answer, people will still waste time reading it" is hardly the best option, yet perfectly normal if not true statement. I think it is enough to say that "even" goes with the implied extreme, regardless if it is best, worst, weirdest, etc..

Comment: @Unreason: On the contrary, for the purposes of stopping people wasting time reading your answer, failing miserably to provide a good one is one of your better options.  Not providing an answer at all would be best, but context suggests that's not an option for some reason.

Comment: @Rhodri, but you are completely mistaken - to know if an answer is any good you have to read it, by which time it is too late! :) Anyway, thank you for the fish, but I was just nitpicking in attempt to suggest a correction of an obviously false statement in otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer edited after [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/674/discussion-between-ham-and-bacon-and-unreason)

There are two interpretation

1. [DUTY](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/should_1)

> Even if I should...

Here *should* takes the meaning of

> **should**
>
> 1. used for talking about what is right, sensible, or correct
>      a. used for saying or asking about the right or sensible thing to do or the right way to behave

(from macmillan), where in your first example *should* takes the meaning of *if*.

> **should**
>   3. used after “if” or instead of “if” for describing a situation that may possibly happen

2. [POSSIBILITY](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/should_3) (when referring to a possible event in the future)

> Even if I should...

can also mean

> Even if I will...

Therefore if you are referring to actions in future you must look at the context. If you use the construct with other tenses the ambiguity is gone.

NOTES:
- "Even should I should..." does not work.
- The word "even" is not important here (which means it works as expected - macmillan: *Even is used for emphasis mainly before a word, a phrase, or a clause beginning with “as,” “if,” or “though.”*)

Comment: "If you should ever" seems to contradict this.

Comment: @language hacker, contradicts what?

Comment: "Should" isn't being used in the first sense.

Comment: @language hacker, I have updated my answer

Comment: From the limited context we have, it hardly seems likely that OP is concerned with the possible 'duty' sense of *should*, so I don't think it's helpful to introduce this right at the start of your answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, hm, not sure: OP start with something that has nothing to do with 'duty' sense, but then attaches 'should' to a conditional phrase. I think it is equally likely that the sense of that 'should' is related to duty.

Comment: haha - I think you've already kicked that one to death with Ham and Bacon, so you'll excuse me if I don't sign up for a rematch! Besides which I seem to recall the whole issue of *could/should* was covered in an earlier question. Whatever - your points are all valid, but I just felt @Rhodri's answer covered new ground re use of *Even if...*, and nicely touched on the slight difference implied by *should* in that context.

Answer (score 1):

They all mean the same thing, basically, even the third example, which is actually "Even if I" added with a "should."

They're also all used to mean that the possibility of me changing my actions, would not change the results i.e.

*Should* in the second and third examples is being used [in this way:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/should)

> (used to express condition): *Were he to arrive, I should be pleased.*

Not as a auxiliary verb which implies obligation to the action, so all three statements mean the same. That's my two coins.

Comment: -1, I disagree, compare "Even if I *should* go to jail, I will not." vs "Even if I go to jail, I will not."

Comment: @Unreason, what's the difference? Besides, in the second one, it should be *went* i.e. Even if I went to jail, I will not.

Comment: @Ham and Bacon, the meaning of "Even if I went/go to jail, I will not" is nonsensical, while "Even if I should go to jail, I will not." is not. This shows that they don't mean the same and that in the construct "Even if I should..." should takes the 1.a meaning from macmillan (see my answer).

Comment: Yep, I agree with that, but the ellipsis of *should* in "Even if I" doesn't make it nonsensical. Try this: "Even if I did go to jail, I will not."

Comment: @Ham and Bacon, I don't see your point, if you agree that the meaning is not the same we are done :) (if not let's take it to chat; also, ellipsis is not the right word here - it is used only when omitting something that is normally *required*, in this case it is not)

Comment: @Unreason, I'm not sure, somehow, I feel that it means the same.

Comment: @Unreason let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/674/discussion-between-ham-and-bacon-and-unreason)

Comment: @Unreason: *Will you compromise on your principles? Even if I go to jail, I will not!"* It's not nonsensical :)

Comment: @psmears, nice one... :)))

Comment: I think all three examples are grammatically disastrous, but especially this one: *Even should I had jumped ...*

Comment: @z7sg, Thinking of better ones...

Comment: "Even if I should ..." can be used either way -- as a subjunctive or as an indicator of liability/obligation. That part of the sentence is naturally ambiguous; you can't really tell which usage is intended until you get to the second half.

Comment: But used in this case, what with the "Even" and the "if", it's quite obvious its usage is a subjunctive, unless I am mistaken, and those words *even* and *if* don't affect it...

Comment: OP is presumably well aware he's using *should* in a 'conditional' sense, so I see no benefit in pointing that out. Even less point in discussing a possible 'obligation' sense that OP *doesn't* intend to apply. The relevant 'nuance' here is that of hypotheticality, as correctly identified by @Rhodri.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank-you for pointing that out, but that what's I've been trying to tell all the other folks for the past 8 hours...

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: I thought as much, though I didn't read through it all. Just to be clear - I have no problem with your answer as it stands. I just think Rhodri's adds that little extra detail about hypotheticality which is what *should* have been the focus of any discussion about differences in meaning. :)